# Coping the value that does not exist

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if we copy a value that does not exist what will be the typeof copied value ?
Is it `null` or `undefined` ?

```
const args = [1]
console.log(...args.slice(1))
```

Here is a concrete example

```
const compose = fns => (...args) =>
  fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc, ...args.slice(1)), args[0]);


const func3 = (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3);

const func2 = x => x ** 2;

const func1 = x => x - 8;

const fnOne = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', 1);
console.log(fnOne); // should be 1081

const fnTwo = compose([func1, func2, func3])('3', -1);
console.log(fnTwo); //should be -8
```

Comment: so what did you see when you tried it?

Comment: you could find this out quickly on your own using codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @epascarello It was empty. But I could not find the typeof.

Comment: In the above example `args.slice(1)` will return empty array `[]`

Comment: @MaheerAli I see now . Thank you!

Comment: `const args = [1];
var x = args.slice(1);
console.log(typeof x, x)` now when you see what x is, you understand why spread operator does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slice` always returns an array, never `undefined`. That array can be empty though.

If a function gets called with less arguments than parameters, the parameters will be `undefined`:

```
  const fn = (a, b) => console.log(a, b);

 fn(1) // a = 1, b = undefined
 // equals
 fn(...[1])  // a = 1, b = undefined
```

Comment: should I adjust my function to the following `fn(...[acc, ...args.slice(1)])`

Comment: No, thats completely equal.

Answer (score 0):

A spreaded empty array returns no parameter.

```js
console.log('>', ...[], '<');
```